# ¿Qué significa la arroba (@) en CSS?

Tags: css, css3

En CSS podemos definir estilos para id's con la almohadilla (`#`) y para clases con el punto (`.`), pero hay algunas reglas que van precedidas por la arroba (`@`) como por ejemplo:

```
@font-face {
    /* definición de fuente propia */
}

@media print {
    /* estilos a la hora de imprimir */
}

@keyframes miAnimacion {
    /* definición de pasos para una animación */
}
```

¿Qué significa la `@` antes de la regla? ¿Cuántas hay y para qué se usan? ¿Qué tienen de especial?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### [Reglas de @](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule)

(Reglas-At o *at-rules*)

Son declaraciones CSS que encapsulan un grupo de reglas, pero no están directamente relacionadas a elementos HTML/XML. Controlan la forma en que se aplican los estilos extendiendo la capacidad de CSS y cada una tiene su propia sintaxis.

**Reglas generales**

Se aplican a todo el CSS

- **[`@charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@charset)** Define el conjunto de caracteres usado en el CSS.
- **[`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@import)** Permite incluir otro CSS.
- **[`@namespace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@namespace)** Establece el XML a ser usado.

**Reglas anidadas**

Pueden estar como declaración de estilo o como condicionales.

- **[`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@media)** Establece reglas condicionales de acuerdo a las características del dispositivos de salida (tamaño de pantalla, tipo de impresora, dispositivos braille, etc.)
- **[`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)** Establece reglas condicionales según el navegador utilizado.
- **[`@document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@document)** Restringe las reglas contenidas según la URL.
- **[`@page`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@page)** Restringe las reglas contenidas para cuando se quiere imprimir (en impresora) el documento.
- **[`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)** Incluye fuentes (tipográficas) externas.
- **[`@keyframes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)** Controla los pasos intermedios en una secuencia de animación.
- **[`@viewport`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport)** Restringe las reglas según el tamaño y orientación de la ventana, especialmente útiles en celulares.
- **[`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style)** Define estilos de contador específicos.
- [**`@font-feature-values`**, *@swash, @ornaments, @annotation, @stylistic, @styleset y @character-variant*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@font-feature-values) Define nombres comunes para la propiedad `font-variant-alternates`.

#### Ejemplos

**1. Definir el conjunto de caracteres UTF-8**

Debe ser el primer elemento en el CSS, y no puede estar precedido por ningún otro caracter.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
```

**2. Definir reglas diferentes según el documento que lo cargue**

Con [@document](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/@document) podemos definir, dentro del mismo CSS, una imagen de fondo para la página principal y otra para las que comienzan con "foro".

```css
@document url(http://dominio.com/index.html) {
    body {
        background-image: url("ppal.jpeg");
    }
}

@document url-prefix(http://dominio.com/foro) {
    body {
        background-image: url("msj.jpeg");
    }
}
```

**3. Usar una fuente de Google Fonts**

En este ejemplo se referencia a la fuente *[Source Sans Pro](https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Source+Sans+Pro)*.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/sourcesanspro/v9/ODelI1aHBYDBqgeIAH2zlNV_2ngZ8dMf8fLgjYEouxg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

y luego se puede usar en el CSS como:

```css
div, p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', 'Otra Fuente', 'etc';
}
```

**4. Incluir otro CSS cuando el dispositivo está en modo apaisado**

En el siguiente, se incluye el CSS externo `ruta_de_otro.css`.

```css
@import url('ruta_de_otro.css') screen and (orientation:landscape);
```

**5. Definir 2 conjuntos de propiedades según compatibilidad**

De esta forma se definen 2 grupos, de acuerdo a si el navegador soporta [propiedades flex](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) o no.

```css
@supports (display: flex) {
    div { display: flex; }
}

@supports not (display: flex) {
    div { display: none; }
}
```

**6. Usar un @media query para diferenciar entre dispositivos**

- Según dimensiones: descripto en [CSS: ¿Qué son los media queries, para qué sirven, cómo se agrupan y cómo implementarlos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/50786/127).
- Según navegador: descripto en *[browser strangeness](https://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.io/css_hacks.html?#safari)*.

Comment: creo que te ganaste la camiseta.. jaja