# Detectar orientanción del dispositivo usando CSS

Tags: html, css

Realizé las pruebas en mi tablet y no sé porque razón no me funcionan los estilos ni en vertical ni en horizontal.

Este es mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<style type="text/css">
    /* Portrait o Vertical */ 
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
     /* Aquí van los estilos para las pantallas en vertical */
     background-color: blue;
} 

/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { 
    /* Aquí van los estilos para las pantallas en horizontal */ 
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Para aplicar los media queries necesitas otros criterios. Tienes que tomar en cuenta los diferentes tamaños, y las principales marcas del mercado. Te recomiendo que leas esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50787/29967 sobre todo el apartado: **Media queries por grupos de dispositivos**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te está funcionando simplemente porque **NO estás aplicando el estilo a ningún elemento `HTML`**, para conseguirlo, tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

      @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
        #background {
          background-color: blue;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
        #background {
          background-color: red;
        }
      }

    </style>
  </head>

<body id="background">

</body>
</html>
```

En el código que te acabo de poner **SÍ se está seleccionando un elemento** (en este caso con **id background**, lo cual el estilo si podrá ser aplicado.

> También te recomiendo que el **`<style>`** lo coloques dentro del
>   **`<head>`** ya que es recomendable **que cuando se reenderizan los elementos `HTML`** el estilo **`CSS`** ya **esté definido**.

**[Aquí tienes una sencilla y rápida guía](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)** para que lo practiques un poco más a fondo.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.