# No funciona el responsive

Tags: css

Tengo una página *responsive*, supuestamente, porque mientras que en la pantalla del ordenador, al redimensionar me lo muestra bien, al abrirlo con un dispositivo de pantalla pequeña (menor de 500px de ancho) no funciona.
Os adjunto el meta que tengo puesto y como están las queries:

> **HTML**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

> **CSS**:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px){......}
@media only screen and (max-width: 501px){......}
```

**[Enlace a la web](http://greym.esy.es/pizzeria/)**

Comment: Tienes puesto `min-width: 501px` por bajo de ese ancho no funcionaran las instrucciones que tengas asociadas

Comment: Cuando puedas, te recomiendo que revises esta pregunta: [CSS: ¿Qué son los media queries, para qué sirven, cómo se agrupan y cómo implementarlos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/50786/29967) y su respuesta.

Comment: Intenta añadir un ejemplo completo y verificable para tu pregunta, por muy simplificado que sea. De ese modo será más fácil encontrar el error.

Comment: he añadido el enlace de donde lo podéis ver

Comment: En la página tienes dos veces el viewport: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` y luego, el que se aplica es éste, porque aparece último: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=960">`. También si es posible, prueba con dos versiones de navegador distintas en el dispositivo móvil.

Comment: Sí funciona: http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/?u=http://greym.esy.es/pizzeria/

Comment: Muchas gracias. El problema era el meta duplicado efectivamente

Answer (score 1):

> En la etiqueta meta usa esto:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

> y si estas empezando desde mobile a desktop utiliza esto:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
       /* Tus Estilos */
}
```

Espero te sirva.