# Calcular porcentaje CSS3

Tags: css, css3

Como puedo calcular ***el equivalente*** a un `width` en `pixeles`?

Osea si tengo:

```
width: 250px;
```

Como lo calculo en `%`? , ***para así hacer mi web apta para todas las resoluciones***

Comment: Si lo que quieres es _hacer mi web apta para todas las resoluciones_, lo que debes crear es un diseño _responsive_, usando para ello media queries. Convertir de px a %  sería un gran dolor de cabeza para lo que quieres hacer, ya que la conversión dependerá siempre del contexto. 250px en un contenedor de 1000px = 25% y en un contenedor de 500px = 50%. Los media queries identifican el tamaño de la pantalla por grupos de dispositivos y en base a eso aplican el tamaño a los elementos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visto que el motivo de tu pregunta es el siguiente:

***para así hacer mi web apta para todas las resoluciones***

Me parece que estás emprendiendo el camino equivocado para lograr ese objetivo.

**Primero**, porque para hacer tu web apta para todas las resoluciones, lo que se usa son los [Media Queries](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/50786/29967):

> *Añadidos en CSS3, los media queries dejan que la presentación del contenido se adapte a un rango específico de dispositivos de salida sin tener que cambiar el contenido en sí. Es lo que se llama en inglés un diseño responsive, o sea, que **se adapta a cada dispositivo según el tamaño de la pantalla**.*

**Segundo**, porque tal conversión sería complicada, ya  que **dependerá siempre del contexto en el que se mostrarán los elementos**.

No obstante, para responder a tu pregunta, la fórmula sería: `elemento/contenedor`:

Por ejemplo, para convertir un elemento de `250px` en un contenedor de `1000px`:

**`250/1000 = 0.25 (o sea, 25%)`**

Pero si el contenedor es de `500px`:

**`250/500 = 0.5 (o sea, 50%)`**

Es decir, es una conversión que va a depender **siempre** del contexto. Dicho de otro modo, la conversión de un elemento de `250px` equivaldría a `25%` en un contexto, `50%` en otro contexto, `n%` en `n` contextos.

---

Para más detalles puedes consultar:

- [CSS PX to Percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22521488/5587982)
- [How do I calculate percentage based on pixels for CSS conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414466/5587982)

Comment: Gracias A. cedano

Answer (score 1):

este método es el recomendado, con `calc` puedes hacer cálculos:

```
:root {
  --width-size1: 250px;
}

.one {
  width: calc(var(--width-size1) - 80%);
}
```

lo que si te aseguro es que hacer una web apta para todo los navegadores se le dice diseño responsive, y para tal caso te recomiendo un patrón de diseño tipo bootstrap o una plantilla basada en esa tecnología, ya que te acortara mucho el diseño...seria interesante que lo tomes en consideración.

Answer (score 1):

El tipo de datos "porcentaje" en css básicamente toma como 100% **la longitud de su contenedor o elemento padre**.

En ese de orden de ideas, un ancho de 250px será equivalente a 25% si su contenedor es de 1000px, o será 50% si el contenedor es de 500px de ancho.

---

Tal vez una unidad de medida que te puede servir más para adaptar tu ancho a todas las resoluciones, es `vw`, que son las iniciales de **viewport width** o el ancho de la zona visible.

`1vw` es igual al 1% de "la ventana", lo cual puede hacerlo más fácil de adaptar en muchos casos.

---

Por último puedes revisar `calc()`, el cuál hace operaciones aritméticas básicas para dar una longitud.

Ejemplo: `calc(50% + 200px)`

Comment: Falta otro -1 y me gano la medalla de "presión de pares".

Answer (score 1):

**calc()**, una función de `CSS3` con la que podemos realizar cálculos con medidas, es decir: sumas, restas, multiplicaciones y divisiones mezclando porcentajes, píxeles o cualquier unidad.
Además, es compatible con todos los navegadores.

```
/* Forma estándar de calc() */
width: calc([Cálculos]);
/* Forma según navegadores de calc() */
width: -webkit-calc([Cálculos]);
width: -moz-calc([Cálculos]);
```

[Ver Aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation)