# No me reconoce los css para IE

Tags: html5, css3, internet-explorer

Estoy intentando crear unos css para IE ya que hay varias cosas que se me descuadran y cuando creo los css, no me reconoce los css y no me hace nada

HTML

```
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
        <link href="/Content/IE/ie.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <![endif]-->
```

div donde está la clase

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-4 section-login" id="col-right">
            <section id="loginForm" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <div>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <div class="form-group">
                    @*<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>*@

                    <p class="text-center"><img src="~/Content/images/logo-evoluciona.png" /></p>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="sbForm">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

CSS

```
.section-login {
    margin-top: 200px;
}
```

cuando le doy a inspeccionar elemento, me aparece bien en el head la llamada al css de IE pero luego no me hace nada, voy a la línea del código donde he puesto la clase y no me la reconoce y no me baja el div los 200px que le puse en el CSS y no sé que estoy haciendo mal para que no me lo reconozca.

Me podéis ayudar por favor

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Los comentarios condicionales no funcionan desde IE 10

> Se ha eliminado el soporte para Comentarios Condicionales en Internet Explorer 10 en modos standards y quirks para mejorar la interoperabilidad y en conformidad con HTML5. Esto significa que los Comentarios Condicionales ahora son tratados como comentarios regulares, como en cualquier otro navegador.
>
> ---
>
> Fuente: [*Conditional comments are no longer supported (Microsoft Docs)*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85)).

O sea que ese comentario condicional sólo te va a funcionar para IE 8 o 9. Esto es cosa del pasado.

Para detectar el navegador, se pueden comprobar con detección de características (*browser hacks* o *CSS hacks*), como por ejemplo:

- http://browserhacks.com/
- https://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/
- https://gist.github.com/vidaaudrey/c16774076391d09e7ec7dbb7ed7a3189

Por ejemplo, **para IE 10 y 11**, la siguiente [regla de @](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/17860/127):

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    /* Acá tus reglas que sólo aplican a IE 10 e IE 11 */
    .clase-ejemplo { color:green; }
}
```

---

Otra opción sería emular a IE 9 con

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

en el `<head>` de la página, pero realmente no te lo recomiendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el `@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none)` me funcionó bien, yo estaba acostumbrado a ponerlo en hacks y era por eso que no me pillaba los css